# How to get page contents after redirect by javascript in php

Tags: php, javascript, redirect, curl

How can I get whole page contents after that page redirect by javascript?

In **executewebpage.php**:

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setOpt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
$url = 'http://www.doredirect.com';
$postfields = array('doredirect'=>'true','trigger'=>'1');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postfields);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
$data = curl_exec($ch);

echo($data);  //In this step, it redirect to page: http://www.finalpage.com

curl_close($ch);
```

How can I get contents of **http://www.finalpage.com**?

**Note:If I don't echo, it don't return anything and don't redirect to any page**

Thank you so much!

Comment: How is it redirecting? Since you have CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION set, it should automatically follow the redirect if it's done using `Location: http://www.finalpage.com` and return the contents of that page. If that's not happening, it seems like the page must be using some other kind of redirect.

Comment: I think it use javascript, I'm not sure because it's not my page and I  haven't enought time to view it's contents before it redirect:D!

Comment: CURL can't execute JavaScript, so it can't follow this redirect.

Comment: Just look at the output of your PHP script to see its contents. Or run curl from the command line.

Comment: Oh! I got it! I trying sth...

Comment: I don't think I can see its contents! It redirect so fast:D

Comment: Read my comment below to see the contents.  Use htmlspecialchars($data);

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using this to view the HTML of the curl response:

```
echo htmlspecialchars($data);
```

It's likely that there is a javascript or meta redirect in there somewhere.  Look for this:

```
window.location...
```

or

```
document.location...
```

or

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=http://finalpage.com" />
```

From there, you can build a regular expression (as others have suggested) to find the URL and then fetch it's contents.

Comment: Do you mean I can get the final url but not the finalpage.com and fetch it's data?

Comment: Here's what's happening - you are loading some data (html) via CURL.  You are then echo'ing that data to the browser.  Something within that data is then telling the browser to redirect to finalpage.com.  This could be happening with 1) Javascript redirect, 2) META redirect, or 3) a HEADER redirect.  You must find the culprit, then parse the CURL response to get the URL, and then do another request to fetch the content of finalpage.com.  Make sense?

Comment: Ok! I found that it use javascript. I really want to make it simple, but it really make me crazy:D! The header get from www.doredirect.com 's dynamic.

Comment: http://www.finalpage.com prevented curl to post directly to it! What can I do now? Help me please:D!

Comment: I am not really sure what you are trying to accomplish.  Some websites have failsafes against hackers... such as not honoring a request which doesn't seem right (such as your case).  For example, ever try loading Google in an iframe?  Doesn't really work.  Same might apply here... finalpage.com says "this isn't a browser request... go f*ck yourself"... aka 404 or empty 200 response ;)

Comment: Oh men!:)! I see! Thank you!I'll find another way to do that.

Comment: I found it, but still have problem :). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12649580/relative-path-in-curl-php.
I'm really a chicken in programming:D!

Answer (score 1):

Go through the html returned and figure out where the redirect is placed in the code. Put the data in a variable, process it with a regex, get the url its redirecting to and get the new page content with a new curl request.

Answer (score -1):

I found out how to do that!

I detected that the **http://www.finalpage.com** resubmit itseft before show contents out. So I used this http://www.mishainthecloud.com/2009/12/screen-scraping-aspnet-application-in.html to curl it and I got whatever I want. Thank everybody!