# cURL get url from redirect

Tags: php, url, redirect, curl

I'm currently using cURL to try and get the URL from a redirect for a website scraper. I only need the url from the website. I've researched on stackoverflow and other sites for the past couple days and have been unsuccessful. The code I'm currently using is from this website:

```
  $url = "http://www.someredirect.com";
  $ch = curl_init($url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.1) Gecko/20061204 Firefox/2.0.0.1');         
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
  $response = curl_exec($ch);
  preg_match_all('/^Location:(.*)$/mi', $response, $matches);
  curl_close($ch);
  echo !empty($matches[1]) ? trim($matches[1][0]) : 'No redirect found';
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `preg_match_all('/^Location:(.*)$/mi', $response, $matches);`, are you trying to match `header('Location:http://google.com');` for example? :/

Comment: Yeah. Trying to parse a Location from the header, but the location tag isn't returned in the header.

Comment: In that case, your code works fine for me.

Answer (score 10):

In your particular case, the server is checking for certain user-agent strings.

When a server checks the user-agent string, it will only respond with a `302` redirect status code when the server sees a "valid" (according to the server) user-agent. Any "invalid" user-agents will not receive the `302` redirect status code response or `Location:` header.

In your particular case, when the server receives a request from an "invalid" user-agent it responds with a `200` OK status code with no text in the response body.

(*Note*: in the code below, the actual URLs provided have been replaced with examples.)

Let's say that `http://www.example.com`'s server checks the User-Agent string and that `http://www.example.com/product/123/` redirects to `http://www.example.org/abc`.

In PHP your solution would be:

```
<?php

$url = 'http://www.example.com/product/123/';

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:21.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/21.0"); // Necessary. The server checks for a valid User-Agent.
curl_exec($ch);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
preg_match_all('/^Location:(.*)$/mi', $response, $matches);
curl_close($ch);

echo !empty($matches[1]) ? trim($matches[1][0]) : 'No redirect found';
```

And, the output of this script would be: `http://www.example.org/abc`.

Comment: Yeah I was noticing that, should've said something. If it's not a technical redirect, but still directs to a different site, how would I go about grabbing the url I want?

Comment: On the commandline you can verify your redirects using `curl`. E.g., `curl -IL http://microsoft.com` will first give you status codes 301, then a 200. When I put in the url you gave me, I get a 200 OK status code on the first URL.

Comment: @Josh Depends on how the redirect is done. This link should be helpful, if the redirect is done in HTML or JavaScript: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12633369/how-to-get-page-contents-after-redirect-by-javascript-in-php

Comment: Updated the solution so that it works for this particular server. Additionally, I replaced the actual URLs provided by @Josh with examples.

Answer (score 4):

Try using this code:

```
function curl_last_url(/*resource*/ $ch, /*int*/ &$maxredirect = null) { 
$mr = $maxredirect === null ? 5 : intval($maxredirect); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false); 
    if ($mr > 0) { 
        echo $mr;
        echo $newurl = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL); 

        $rch = curl_copy_handle($ch); 
        curl_setopt($rch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true); 
        curl_setopt($rch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true); 
        curl_setopt($rch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, false); 
        curl_setopt($rch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
        do { 
            curl_setopt($rch, CURLOPT_URL, $newurl); 
            $header = curl_exec($rch); 
            if (curl_errno($rch)) { 
                $code = 0; 
            } else { 
                $code = curl_getinfo($rch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE); 
                echo $code;
                if ($code == 301 || $code == 302) { 
                    preg_match('/Location:(.*?)\n/', $header, $matches); 
                    $newurl = trim(array_pop($matches)); 
                } else { 
                    $code = 0; 
                } 
            } 
        } while ($code && --$mr); 
        curl_close($rch); 
        if (!$mr) { 
            if ($maxredirect === null) { 
                trigger_error('Too many redirects. When following redirects, libcurl hit the maximum amount.', E_USER_WARNING); 
            } else { 
                $maxredirect = 0; 
            } 
            return false; 
        } 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $newurl); 
    } 
return $newurl;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

For me, this worked (with $in_addr given, start url as a string):

```
$ch = curl_init($in_addr);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
curl_exec($ch);
$out_addr = curl_getinfo($ch,  CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);
curl_close($ch);
```

$out_addr now contains the effective url.